# jodd http client How to set up Ignore certificates

Tags: java, https, httpclient, jodd

The site i am using is that of a https protocol,so i want to use Ignore certificates.But I am unable to set the ignore certificate.

```
public class JoddHttpClientDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         SpringApplication.run(JoddHttpClientDemoApplication.class, args);
         HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.get("https://xxxxx.com?0.6891255003788694").
            header("Referer","https://xxxxx.com/x.jsp");
         HttpResponse response = request.send();
         System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error like this,

> jodd.http.HttpException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Comment: May you add the complete stack trace please?

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: @игор 
thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to newest Jodd v3.8.1. There you have the following method: `trustAllCerts`. It will trust all certificates :) Use it like this:

```
HttpRequest
    .get("https://xxxxx.com?0.6891255003788694")
    .header("Referer","https://xxxxx.com/x.jsp")
    .trustAllCerts(true);
```

Comment: i can delete my IgnoreCertificatesSocket.java